# Decoding base64 doesn't work with photo received (via MQTT)

Tags: java, base64

I'm sending a photo via MQTT, and trying to save a copy of that. 
This is what the receiver does:

```
connectMQTTAsReceiver("Controller", "tcp://m2m.eclipse.org:1883", "robot");
byte[] photoByte=receiveMQTT.getBytes();
File photo=new File("image2.jpg");
photo.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(photo);
outputStream.write(photoByte);
outputStream.close();
```

With this, the photo is saved but it's completely white. 
Then I tried doing this:

```
connectMQTTAsReceiver("Controller", "tcp://m2m.eclipse.org:1883", "robot");
byte[] photoByte=Base64.getDecoder().decode(receiveMQTT().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(photoByte);
System.out.println("Received");
BufferedImage bufferedImage;
try {
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(in);
    File outputfile = new File("image3.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character -1e
```

Comment: Why did you decide that the value you received is supposed to be in base64? Usually base64 information is character-based, not byte-based. Also, are you sure it is supposed to return a JPG?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, I'm sure it has to retun a JPG. How do I know instead if it's in base64 or else?

Comment: Well, your API documentation is the only thing that tells you what is returned and in what  format. You can't just decide it's base64. Have you checked if that buffered image that you created can be displayed, before trying to write it?